# Scene loaded from asset bundle is not animating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have a very simple scene, a cube with a script that manages its rotation.

I generate a asset bundle from the entire scene, and when I load this scene, the cube appears in the screen, but the rotation does not work. The cube is static, like as the scene didn't load properly.

This is the code that i use to load the scene:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class TouchButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button yourButton;

    void Start()
    {
        Button btn = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {       
        string url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/0mm336mfxvh83gp/simple?dl=0";
        WWW wwwObj = new WWW(url);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForReq(wwwObj));
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForReq(WWW wwwObj)
    {
        yield return wwwObj;
        AssetBundle bundle = wwwObj.assetBundle;
        if (wwwObj.error == null) {         
            string[] scenePaths = bundle.GetAllScenePaths ();

            SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene", LoadSceneMode.Single);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May be trouble is the unity does not support runtime compilation of script from asset bundle?

Comment: Is that a fact ? But how an asset bundle can be used for an game DLC then ? If the scripts don't work ?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/scriptsinassetbundles.html